# Markdown help is unreadable on Area 51

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51

It is hard to read the [formatted Markdown help](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help) on Area 51:

[image: Screenshot of Area 51's Markdown help]

Comment: Just highlight the text.  That fixes it.

Comment: "hard" is an understatement!

Comment: @Justin Sounds like [status-bydesign] to me :)

Comment: @Michael, yup.  It's a security measure.

Comment: I can read it just fine...

Comment: Well, it is *Area 51*! Stuff from there gets redacted all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has now been fixed. https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help