# Add [locked] for Meta bugs and feature requests

Tags: feature-request, meta, locked

I recently reported [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76913/markdown-help-is-unreadable-on-area-51) on Meta.

It was promptly fixed and the tag [status-completed] added, all fine.

However, shouldn't there be a **lock** feature for these types of questions. It doesn't require any more editing/answers/comments.

In the event of a regression a vote to re-open should be available.

Comment: Bugs [can always return](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65567/deleted-comments-persist-in-the-global-inbox/78084#comment-182003). Vote to re-open then seems a lot of work. Why is it bothering you you to leave the questions open?

Comment: @Arjan Should flesh that out and post it as an answer, I suggest.

Comment: @Grace, (meanwhile?) the question itself also mentions regression (which I didn't notice earlier), so surely my comment is not an answer any longer?

Comment: Also, folks might not agree right after something gets `status-completed`.

Comment: @Arjan You fleshed out your comment to note that voting to reopen a locked item (which is mod only, anyway, and terribly cumbersome) is a lot of work... so it seems like it can still be an answer.

Comment: I guess I'll wait to see *why* the OP thinks it's a problem. But: I'll upvote any answer that claims the same, @Grace ;-) (I learned a new word, or term, *fleshing out*, today!)

Answer (score 3):

Seems a lot of extra work for no benefit.

Do you see any cases of abuse where things that are [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) are being answered still? Mods have a lot of work to do already, if we're going to give them *more* work, we should have a good reason.

Also as others have mentioned, what if people disagree with the way a bug was fixed or find more issues with it or ned to discuss further or the bug comes back or...

I just don't see how this could be helpful, and *do* see how it could be harmful.

Comment: HAHA thanks @Grace I forgot the proper syntax. Also love the changelog comment ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Mods already have the ability to lock posts, so the functionality you're asking for already exists in a more general context. So, the question is whether or not to use it.

Generally speaking, [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) questions stay open and available so other users can point out regressions. That is, the question is neither *locked* nor *closed*. I should also point out that any user with < 3k rep pretty much has no real way of drawing attention to a closed question (edit/retag + comment is weak at best). Even at 3k, a reopen vote + comment may not do much as only 10k users will see that in the tools. This doesn't make sense, particularly for an urgent issue (i.e., XSS).

Exceptions to this rule include localized issues such as merging user accounts. Once it's done, it's done. (For this specific example, once it's complete, the question itself is usually *deleted* as it's no longer relevant or valuable to keep around.) Even so, a closed question still allows users to comment, so it's not entirely unavailable.

Really, I don't see any advantage to close (generally) or lock a [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) question.