# The colors of area51 editing help make the text unreadable

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, area-51

On the https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help there is a yellow text on yellow background. The text is a little hard to read.

There was a bug ["Markdown help is unreadable on Area 51"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76913/markdown-help-is-unreadable-on-area-51), but I suspect that something has been changed in the meantime.

http://arsen7.pl/area51_help_colors.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fix will be deployed soon.